# Update to gnome 3.6 from 3.4 in debian wheezy

Tags: debian, gnome3, repository, debian-wheezy, gnome-shell

So I have a gnome 3.4 with my debian wheezy distro.

How can I upgrade it to 3.6? I tried searching repos, but could not find anything. The only thing I found was for Ubuntu, and [the solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/210207) 404'd on me on update. What should I do?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stick to Debian stable/testing/unstable packages, I think you are out of luck. Debian is usually cautiously slow in updating its packages. If you are willing to use packages from Debian's [experimental](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianExperimental) repo, I did notice that some GNOME 3.6 packages are available there (like [gnome-shell](http://packages.debian.org/experimental/gnome-shell)), but keep in mind that these packages are not guaranteed to work at all and may break your system (the same goes for installing most Ubuntu PPAs).